# How to create a Microsoft Team using a Queue Triggered Azure Function writed in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-teams, queuetrigger

I want to create a Team by using an azure function triggered by an Azure Queue.
Unfortunetly when I run the code it is not working inside the Azure Function.

I'm wondering. Is there a way to create a Microsoft Team using PowerShell inside an Azure Function ?

```
Import-module MicrosoftTeams
$group = New-Team -MailNickname "teamTitle" -displayname "teamTitle" -Visibility "private"
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $group.GroupId -User "user@etc.com"
New-TeamChannel -GroupId $group.GroupId -DisplayName "General"
```

Working locally. Not working within the Azure Function.

Bellow the error i'm getting :

```
ERROR: Import-Module : The specified module 'MicrosoftTeams' was not loaded because no valid
module file was found in any module directory. At D:\home\site\wwwroot\CreateTeam\run.ps1:3
char:1 + Import-Module MicrosoftTeams +  [...]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, your Function app does not have the MicrosoftTeams module installed. You need to include a reference to this module to the `requirements.psd1` file (see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management for more details).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The error message is gone. Now I have to find a way to use the command **Connect-MicrosoftTeams**
This command displays a pop-up that I cannot fill when inside an Azure Function.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this module is not yet natively integrated into the azure functions under powershell

To see all the available packages go in App Service -> Advanced Tools -> DebugConsole -> Powershell and run :

```
Write-Output ‘Getting PowerShell Module’
$result = Get-Module -ListAvailable |
Select-Object Name, Version, ModuleBase |
Sort-Object -Property Name |
Format-Table -wrap |
Out-String
Write-output `n$result
```

To manually add a package, It is necessary to create a directory "Module" At the same level as the directory of the function, They will be automatically preloaded.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell step "Function app-level Modules folder")

Answer (score 0):

After installation of the module. use below code in your script to automate the process.

```
$securedpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $securedpassword )
$res = Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $mycredentials
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying me. When i follow yours leads I'm getting the following error message:   
    ERROR: Connect-MicrosoftTeams : **password_required_for_managed_user**: Password    is required for managed user At D:\home\site\wwwroot\CreateTeam\run.ps1